# Is there a way to run only Features in parallel tests on specflow?

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, specflow

I'm currently working on a project that tests some functionalities on a web application that I developed. It works just fine, but I need to run these features in parallel to buy time.

By changing the "testThreadCount" attribute I can run my tests in parallel. My problem is: My features are independent, but my scenarios are not. Example:

```
    Feature: Test sql insert

    Scenario: 1 - Insert client on the database
    Given I insert my credentials
    And I insert some data on my sql database
    Then my client gets inserted succesfully

    Scenario: 2 - Check if client exists
    Given The above scenario is succesful
    And I log in on my web application
    When I'm on the dashboard
    Then The client should be there
```

Is there a way to run in parallel only my different features? When I click on "Run selected tests", It priorizes complete features over different ones. I need wait for the first scenario to complete before running the next one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building your scenarios up like that is a really bad practice and should be avoided as much as possible.  That being said if it must be done.  You can turn on parallelization at the feature level.

If you are using NUnit you can add  `[assembly: Parallelizable(ParallelScope.Fixtures)]` at the assembly level.

Xunit should by default run tests in parallel by class or feature in this case. Meaning all tests within a feature will run in serially.

You should still consider refactoring your scenarios so they are not dependent on each other I've been down that road before and it eventually becomes an unmanageable nightmare.

Comment: I know it isn't the best practice, but it is no other way. I'm using specrun, but I should be able to implement that. Thanks!

Comment: By doing this, it runs tests as a ladder. It is better than completely random, but I was wondering if there is another way to customize my tests to run in which order I want...

Answer (score 0):

Well... I found a work around that managed to make it work on SpecRun.

I just needed to run my features one by one and make another application manage the traffic line, so I developed an application with Windows Forms that does just that.

May not be the best way to approuch this problem, but given my lack of time and the circunstances, it did a great job.